# CakePHP - Set up Auth model to only use one password field, no username

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I need an auth system that allows you to log in with a predefined unique password only.

How do I configure the Auth component to only require the password field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your very own [custom authorize object](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects) which can use whatever you like.

In this class you would do your lookup using one field and return true / false if the user is allowed access.